vuejs3 and vite import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL not working
Hello I'm trying to get base url from .env file. And I'm getting undefined.
I have tried some stack overflow answers and documentation but it didn't help.
console.log('env', import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL)


My .env file.

And I don't understand why this works?
console.log('env', import.meta.env.BASE_URL)



Few things to double-check so that we're sure that it works well:

.env is at the root of your project (aka at the same level as package.json, .gitignore etc)
prefer using a double quote for your variables aka VITE_NICE="hello"

Then, this should be working well in any .vue file
<script setup>
console.log('env', import.meta.env.VITE_NICE)
</script>

Official docs page.
This is how the directory should look like (aka .env should be outside of the src directory).


Yes .env is in root folder and I didn't use any "", I will try that now.

.env is in src folder and I used "" and it's not working.

@Dusan this could sometimes work without the double-quotes (if letters only for example), but given the fact that it's a / here, might be interpreted in some different way or need an escape. I took the habit of wrapping every value into double quotes to be sure that it never fails. .env should be at the root directory, so 1 level higher than src.

.env should be at the root directory
Now it works. Thanks!
